# Lengend overlap with graph in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the graph through pandas but legend keeps on overlapping with the graph. I tried putting legend on the right side but it still showing with graph

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/10659910)

Comment: Specifically, `ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)